# Pop-up (InfoBubble) on marker click Here maps

Tags: android, popup, here-api, infobubble, bubble-popup

I want to configure my map using HERE FREE SDK so when i click on a marker a pop-up shows up with some Texts , i've tried InfoBubble but i think that's not working anymore, also i wanted to try MapOverlay but it seems that it's limited to JS only.
so here's my code :

```
MapMarker myMapMarker =  new MapMarker(new GeoCoordinate(LAT, LNG), myImage);

map.addMapObject(myMapMarker);
MapGesture.OnGestureListener listener = new MapGesture.OnGestureListener.OnGestureListenerAdapter() {
    @Override
    public boolean onMapObjectsSelected(List<ViewObject> objects) {
        for (ViewObject viewObj : objects) {
            if (viewObj.getBaseType() == ViewObject.Type.USER_OBJECT) {
                if (((MapObject)viewObj).getType() == MapObject.Type.MARKER) {
                        map.setInfoBubbleAdapter( new Map.InfoBubbleAdapter() {
                        @Override
                        public View getInfoBubbleContents(MapMarker mapMarker) {
                            return null;
                        }

                        @Override
                        public View getInfoBubble(MapMarker mapMarker) {
                            View Bubble;

                            Bubble =LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.bubble_layout,       container, false);
                            TextView nom = Bubble.findViewById( R.id.nomecole );
                            nom.setText( "School" );
                            return Bubble;
                        }
                    } );
                    ((MapObject)viewObj).setVisible(false);
                }
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
};
```

and for my bubble layout :
`

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/nomecole"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="-4dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/nom"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textSize="13sp" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

`

Answer (score 0):

You must call `MapMarker.showInfoBubble()` to show and `MapMarker.hideInfoBubble()` to hide info bubble.

Also you may need to remove the line that hides MapMarker so the marker stays visible after it was clicked. This line:

```
((MapObject)viewObj).setVisible(false);
```

Comment: Hi, was it deleted or replaced with something else? I can find this neither in the doc nor in the API.

Comment: This API was deleted since then. As of now, you can use MapOverlay API to attach android's View to the geo coordinate on the map.